# Read large data into Model using Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, n-triples

I need to load large .nt file into a Model using Jena.

RDFDataMgr.read(model, filename);

The problem is I a have Java Error Memory.
There is any way to load large rdf(nt) data file into Jena Model.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: What sort of model is it? A memory-based one? If so, either you need to give the JVM more space or switch to using a persistent store like TDB (in the Apache jena distribution).  It also means you don't need to load it each time.

Comment: If it is a TDB backed model, then possibly it is a singe transaction that exceeds the heap in its working space.  You can load with the bulk loader "tdhloader" first or use TDB2 or break the loading into chunks.

Comment: Are you the same guy that already asked on the mailing list today and yesterday? What means *large*?

Comment: @AKSW  no it's my first question about the topic.

Comment: Thank's @AndyS yes its a memory-based model.

Comment: Size of the dataset? How much Java heap?

Comment: 20.46 GB :) @AKSW

Comment: Ok, that's pretty large given that it's N-Triples format. I'd strongly suggest using a proper triple store like TDB as Andy suggested. In-memory clearly needs a huge amount of RAM.

Comment: Ok Thanks for all, I will use StreamRDF and implement the void triple in StreamRDFBase to add triples in the graph of model: 
         model.getGraph().add(triple); It's very slow but there is no Memory error.